# Burninate the [inside] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

This one made me really ROFL: [inside](/questions/tagged/inside).

From what I saw *inside* that list there is little on SO that should not be tagged as such!

I didn't browse through the whole ~200 tagged questions (I stopped at 50 :-) so I'm not *completely* sure it hasn't a legitimate use, but I can't help thinking this really deserves the attentions of Trogdor!

Comment: I want to know why there are 4 people following that tag. Weird. Anyway, yes, needs to be killed.

Comment: @Wooble Probably they are really *inside* it. :-)

Comment: *sharpening my tools* I see no reason why this tag should not be burned with the fire of a thousand suns.  Speak now, or too bad too sad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awful, unnecessary tag.

I retagged all 200+ questions containing [inside](/questions/tagged/inside) - it is now gone.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: I sure hope it burned [inside]-out.